# Traduction de "the condition/reasoning fails"

Tags: traduction, anglais, mathématiques

Comment traduire "*Since this equation's left hand side isn't equal to the right hand side, the condition/reasoning fails (to prove this theorem)*" ?

Tentatives:

1. La base/le fondement/le préalable échouent. 
   [Aucun résultat sur Google](https://www.google.com.hk/search?q=%22le+fondement+manque%22&oq=%22le+fondement+manque%22)
2. La base/le fondement/le préalable ratent. 
   [Aucun résultat sur Google](https://www.google.com.hk/search?q=%22le+fondement+manque%22&oq=%22le+fondement+manque%22)
3. La base/le fondement/le préalable manquent. 
   [Quelques résultats](https://www.google.com.hk/search?q=%22le+fondement+manque%22&oq=%22le+fondement+manque%22)

Au demeurant, je ne souhaite pas signifier *manquer*, qui est plus détourné, évasif, et fuyant ?

**Question supplémentaire :** Existe-t-il un seul mot/verbe pour signaler l'acception de *"fail"*,
hormis « ne + un verbe quelconque qui témoigne le succès + pas » ?

Comment: Il manque du contexte. On ne sait pas vraiment quelle est la question.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez: Merci de me le faire savoir. Je viens d'en ajouter. C'est mieux ?

Answer (score 2):

En français on dit respectivement « la condition n'est pas remplie » et « ce raisonnement est incorrect ». On entend aussi « raisonnement [faux](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/faux) », ou « raisonnement [erroné](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/erron%C3%A9) ».

Answer (score 1):

*Fail* a effectivement plusieurs sens et la citation manque de contexte pour déterminer ce qui conviendrait le mieux.

**Échouer** et **rater** (exemples 1 et 2) implique la présence préalable d'une condition déterminée dont le résultat est un échec.

**Manquer** (exemple 3) implique l'absence de condition.

Selon les cas on pourrait suggérer des traductions :
« L'échec de... » (pour les cas 1et 2)
« L'absence de...» (pour le cas 3)

Et le mot *fail* peut aussi être rendu par une simple négation quand il est suivi d'un verbe :
*Present conditions fail to meet the standards.*    Les conditions actuelles ne respectent pas les standards.
*Your reasoning fails to prove..*  Ton raisonnement ne prouve pas que ... / n'arrive pas à prouver que...

Answer (score 0):

En première réaction, délier le verbe du sujet : à chaque nuance de traduction son action :

> - Le fondement s'effondre
> - La condition est abandonnée
> - Le préalable disparaît

Answer (score 0):

Quelque chose du genre

> Puisque les deux membres de l'équation ne sont pas égaux, le raisonnement précédent ne permet pas de démontrer le théorème.